# Apache Beam: maintaining state in distributed KV table

Tags: apache-beam

I'm trying to better understand Beam computation model and to check if my problem is solvable within this model.

Suppose I have a stream of events,

```
class Event {
    public int userId;
    public int score;
}
```

I want to build pipeline that:

- reads a stream of `Event`s
- maintains distributed KV table (we might use Apache Cassandra or any other similar system)

  - key is `userId`
  - value is maximum score for user

I've read about [stateful processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/)
and as far as I understand it's easy to maintain maximum score for user inside StatefulParDo. But how such state is stored is Beam implementation detail and this state is not available outside StatefulParDo function.

Is it possible to keep such state in well defined format in some sort of KV storage available for external consumers (readers outside of my pipeline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to pick either Beam State API or an external storage system.

Exactly where Beam State is stored is up to the runner. You cannot directly access such state outside the State API.

If you decide to use the external storage path, you could write to such a storage system from a Beam `ParDo`. But you'll have to handle performance when reading/writing and consistency of such data. Also you have to assume that any Beam step might fail and may be re-run by the runner (hence should prevent duplicate writes).